# Bootstrapping with card and for loop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, card

I'm trying to implement card bootstrapping in my .html but I cannot get it to be centered. Please see the code below and help

```
<h1> 10 Games Recommended Based on {{ selected }} </h1>

        <div class = "container">
        
        <div class="recommendations">
  
            {% for name in names_list %}
            <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card text-center" style="Max-width: 30%;">
                  <!-- <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."> -->
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"> <a href = "{{ games[name]['url'] }}" target = "popup">{{ name }}</a></h5>
                    <div class = 'card-body'>
                        <p1 class = "card-text">Overall Reviews: {{games[name]['rating'] }}</p1>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        
        </div>
        </div>
```

I apologize for the mess but the way my app is giving results is pushed to the left like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvDdl.png).

My style is below

```
<style>
            p {font-size: 30px;}
            p1 {font-size: 13px;}
            a {color:navy;
                font-size: 20px;}
            body {text-align: center;}
            body {background-color: lightblue;}        
</style>
```

Is there anyway I can center these or align them side by side when using loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `.row` and `.col` classes. Add them to make it.

```html
<h1>10 Games Recommended Based on {{ selected }}</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="recommendations">
      {% for name in names_list %}
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="card-group">
          <div class="card text-center" style="max-width: 30%">
            <!-- <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..."> -->
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">
                <a href="{{ games[name]['url'] }}" target="popup">{{ name }}</a>
              </h5>
              <div class="card-body">
                <p1 class="card-text"
                >Overall Reviews: {{games[name]['rating'] }}</p1
                >
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just note that `.col-3` is supposed to be repeated and `.row` should be parent.

Comment: that just made all my contents in a card really narrow

Comment: @JamesLee Try using `.col-6` or `.col-4`... Did that work?

Comment: still the same result. seems like the for loop is making the position on the left for all entries and recognizing each one as a new entry

Comment: @JamesLee Can you show me the full generated code in a service like https://JSBin.com or https://CodePen.io or something?

Comment: I actually had comments in the html file and once i deleted them your code totally worked!

Comment: @JamesLee Awesome! 